# check environment variable from pl/sql

Tags: plsql

How to check/display value of operating system variable from pl/sql in simplest possible way.
When I use sqlplus it just like below

```
SQL> host echo $NLS_LANG
POLAND_POLISH.EE8MSWIN1250

SQL>
```

Comment: PL/SQL runs on the **server**. `NLS_LANG` is a variable that the _client_ sets so your question doesn't really make sense. You are probably looking for something like `select * from nls_session_parameters`

Comment: ok, my mistake. Forget about $NLS_LANG - let me call any variable from OS environment.

Comment: in addition In my case server host equal client host :)

Comment: Check this link (`GET_ENV` function): http://psoug.org/reference/dbms_system.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access operating system variables you can use dbms_system.get_env function. Note that, because PL/SQL is executed on server, you access server variables and not client variables:

```
DECLARE
    folder   VARCHAR2(512);
BEGIN
    DBMS_SYSTEM.get_env('ORACLE_HOME', folder);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(folder);
END;
```